# how to specify bundle.js.map(source map) file path to devtools

Tags: html, webpack, bundler

I am using parcel-bundler to bundle my js files and it is output located in

```
public
  js
    bundle.js
    bundle.js.map
```

so, I linked bundle.js file to html and while serving files ,the browser devtools trying to load map file from wrong path i.e `DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for http://localhost:3000/bundle.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE`.so it should rather look at `http://localhost:3000/js/bundle.js.map`. How to make it do that??

also got other error
`bundle.js:9463 Refused to connect to 'ws://localhost:55561/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.`

it is showing this is due to

```
module.bundle.Module = Module;
var checkedAssets, assetsToAccept;
var parent = module.bundle.parent;

if ((!parent || !parent.isParcelRequire) && typeof WebSocket !== 'undefined') {
  var hostname = "" || location.hostname;
  var protocol = location.protocol === 'https:' ? 'wss' : 'ws';
  var ws = new WebSocket(protocol + '://' + hostname + ':' + "55561" + '/');
```

that last line ,why is it trying to connect to 55561 port ?? i think this is added after bundling js files.

Comment: Parcel was trying to connect to your 55561 port to enable [Hot Module Replacement](https://en.parceljs.org/hmr.html) over a websocket; meaning you edit a file and parcel redeploys it to your browser w/o need to refresh the page.